# Quitar simbolo \ de string php

Tags: php, html

Cómo sería el mejor método para quitar `\` de un string?

```html
$ret = "App\Service";
$string = str_replace("\", "", $ret );
```

Comment: Por qué caracter lo reemplazarías?

Comment: Deseo quitarlo, o reemplazarlo por vacio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No te funciona porque el caracter `\` es un caracter de escape puedes colocarlo de la siguiente forma:

```php
$ret = "App\Service";
$string = str_replace('\\','', $ret);
```

---

**Explicación**

Los caracteres de escape o secuencia de escape se usan para expresar caracteres especiales como por ejemplo

- **Tab** representado por `\t`
- **Salto de Linea** representado por `\n`

---

**Nota (Respondiendo a la consulta de @ordago)**

No tiene nada que ver con la función `str_replace`, sino mas bien con el parámetro que le estamos pasando a la función, Cuando indicamos

```php
str_replace("\", "", $ret );
```

Al pasarle a la función el parámetro `"\"` estamos indicándole que vamos a pasar un `String` porque empezamos con el carácter `"` y después viene un carácter de escape `\` seguido de otro carácter `"`, que debería ser el cierre de la cadena pero como antes esta la barra invertida lo escapa y lo toma justo como el carácter que vamos a remplazar el cual seria `"` y por ende no hay cierre de la cadena de caracteres lo que nos daría un error en PHP por no haber un carácter de cierre del `String`, como se ve en el resaltado de la sintaxis.

En cambio con el String `"App\Service"` no sucede porque es un String con sus caracteres de apertura y cierre. En el enlace tiene una explicación mas detallada. Espero haber contestado a tu pregunta.

---

Dejo un enlace a la documentación de **PHP** para una explicación mas detallada de las [Secuencias de Escape](https://www.php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar por qué al hacer `str_replace` tienes que escapar las barras, pero sin embargo en `"App\Service"` no es necesario?

Comment: Perdón por seguir tocando las narices, y ante todo gracias por responder, pero entiendo que si la cadena que quisieramos renombrar se llamase "App\news" habría que escapar la barra para que no se interpretase como un salto de línea (\n). Sin embargo \S es también una secuencia de escape, tal y como indica el enlace que has facilitado y en este caso no hace falta escapar la barra para que la salida sea la correcta.

Comment: A lo que voy es que habría que escapar esa barra. Esto funciona de chiripa con `App\Service`, pero si fuese `App\news`, `App\television`, `App\xyz` no funcionaría correctamente sin escaparla.

Comment: No habría que escaparla porque el String es completo y se lee completo por el intérprete, generalmente los caracteres especiales como \n \t \s no los vemos en los String como caracteres legibles

Comment: Si pruebas a ejecutarlo con "App\television", verás que te genera `"App     elevision"` En lugar de `"Apptelevision"`: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/22d49e18cc062534eb86404ea5c745d8555fa6c2

Comment: Si tienes razón no me había percatado de eso, pero encontré una forma no seria la mas elegante pero solucionaría el problema te dejo el enlace http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0953a084bda5efa3307a2cf79b43377a76989ade

Answer (score -1):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
$ret = "App\Service";
$string = str_replace('\','', $ret);
```

Comment: Así es como lo tengo, y no funciona

Comment: @Pelukosa Fijate que no es exactamente lo mismo, porque él está usando comillas simples `'\'`, pero en tu caso es con comillas dobles `"\"`. De todos modos tiene apariencia de que no iba a funcionar de ninguna de las dos maneras.